# Too Many Objects causing out of memory exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Quick overview of my situation:
I get text files on a scheduled basis which are split by character count, I am developing an app which splits each row out into a list of models depending on which file its Parsing. E.G. A Persons Text file 300 lines long will create a list of a custom model "Person". each item in the list is a line in the file. It is doing this via the below:

```
    private static List<Person> InitializePeople(DataManager dm, string filePath)
    {
        List<Person> people= new List<Person>();
            //Get lines from file to loop through
            foreach (var line in dm.GetDataLinesFromFile(filePath).ToList())
            {
               Person person = new Person();
               //This splits out the character counted split line 
               //into the models format and adds it to a list
               people.Add((Person)dm.GetFormattedData(person, new FormatManger(), line));
            }
        return people;
     }
```

This works fine until I get a file that is millions of lines long. As you can see i am commiting a cheeky NONO in the loop in which I am instantiating a new object each time it loops. This is I believe where my issue lies, it starts struggling for memory when miilions of objects are being instantiated. What is a better way of doing this? Some other way that is more memory effecient? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes; don't try to create millions of objects.  You should probably use a database.

Comment: Do you need them all in memory at the same time? If not, use `IEnumerable<string> File.ReadLines()` and `yield return`, omit the `ToList()`.

Comment: The issue is not with creating the object inside the loop but the list you are maintaining which will grow based on the size. By the way what do you do with the list?

Comment: Im putting this data in the list because i want some flexibilty with what I do with it e.g. take it and put it in a file, put it in a DB, maybe filter it down for some other purpose I have not forseen. I didnt want to make an assumption that this data will be going into a DB

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks for this but can you explain what you mean a little more? Im not sure I understand

Comment: Also note that the `person` variable is never used. I can't imagine it uses up much memory on its own (unless it has thousands of fields), but it isn't necessary.

Comment: @Eilon My bad see edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not *materialize* the data (i.e. avoid `ToList()`, `ToArray()` etc.) work with IEnumerable only.

First, check `dm.GetFormattedData` implementation it should be something like

```
  public IEnumerable<String> GetDataLinesFromFile(filePath) {
    // Check that neither ReadAllLines nor ReadAllText is there
    // Check absence of ToList() and ToArray() as well
    return File
      .ReadLines(filePath) // the only possible way of reading file
      .Select(...) // possible, but not necessary part
      .Where(...); // possible, but not necessary part
  }
```

then redesign `InitializePeople` into something like that:

```
   // Note IEnumerable<Person> instead of List<Person>
   public static IEnumerable<Person> InitializePeople(DataManager dm, string filePath) {
    //TODO: what's "nmy"?
    //TODO: do you really want new FormatManger() for each People instance?
    return GetDataLinesFromFile(filePath)
      .Select(line => (Person)dm.GetFormattedData(nmy, new FormatManger(), line));  
  }
```

And so with the help of *Linq* you can have a lot of flexibility, e.g.

```
  File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt", InitializePeople(dm, @"C:\People.txt")
   .Where(people => people.LastName == "Smith")
   .Select(people => String.Format("{0} is {1} years old", people.FirstName, people.Age));
```

Comment: Thanks ill give this ago, can you explain why materializing data is bad?

Comment: @Srb1313711: it's not bad in general case, it's bad in *your case* because materialization creates in-memory list(s) of millions of items. I suggest *streaming*: item after item processing.

Comment: Thank you for this, it was very helpful and looks like it has resolved my issue!

Answer (score 1):

The list of `People` gets too large to keep in memory. I suggest doing it in chunks and processing each chunk before processing the next one.
If you change your method signature to accept chunk size and position `private static List<Person> InitializePeople(DataManager dm, string filePath, int chunkSize, out int position)` you can achieve this. That way, you wouldn't have to read the entire file, only skip to certain line and then read the desired amount of records.

The pseudo code would look like:

```
var position = 0
var people = []
while (count (people = InitializePeople(dataManager, file, 250, out position) > 0)
    do something with people
    position += count people
```

Comment: Thanks for this, ill give it a whirl and let you know how it goes

Comment: I tried going done this route by found Dmitrys response a little more elegant. Thanks again for the help still!

Comment: I agree, his solution is more elegant. Glad you fixed the problem.